# Domain Address Change

Tags: civimail

I am looking to send a Mailing out, and unfortunately, it looks like the domain address has been changed and is incorrect. The Domain Address populates to San Antonio Texas vs. Oakland California. How can I change the domain address to be from California?

Answer (score 2):

It's under Administer - Communications - Organization Address.

More information: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/installation-and-basic-set-up/#organization-address-and-contact-info